# Is it possible to access a SharePoint 2010 list using multi threading in a web part?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am trying to access the items in a SharePoint 2010 list from a custom webpart. When using threading, the List.ItemCount property is accurate, but the item collection is empty. Has anyone found a way around this? My code for accessing the list is below:

```
    protected override void RenderContents(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        Thread wThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteW));
        //only showing one thread for simplicity
        wThread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        while (threadcount > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(400);
        }
        lblGreeting.RenderControl(writer);

    }

    public void WriteW()
    {
        lock (lockobject)
        {
            threadcount++;
        }
        SPSite spsConflictSite = new SPSite("http://myserver/mysite");
        SPWeb spwConflictWeb = spsConflictSite.OpenWeb();
        SPList splConflictList = spwConflictWeb.Lists["Thread Tester List"];
        DataTable myTable = splConflictList.Items.GetDataTable();
            lblGreeting.Text += " " + myTable.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();
            spsConflictSite.Dispose();
        lock (lockobject)
        {
            threadcount--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't say for positive and I'd like to hear the answer as I have an SP web part I'd love to multithread.  However, you do have concurrency issues in the code you've displayed.  While you're locking around the writing of your `threadcount` member variable in the `WriteW` method, you should be doing the same around the reading of it in the `RenderContents` method.

Comment: Also, while you are indeed properly `Dispose`-ing of `spsConflictSite`, you should be doing the same with `spwConflictWeb` and `myTable` since they both implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This is, for the most part, a hello world version of the real program made for testing the list access problem. I left out a lot for simplicity.

Comment: 2 questions: 1) Does it work when not using threads? 2) Is the URL external to the context the web part will be running?

Comment: 1) yes, without threads it works fine 2) no. it is in the same site collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think using Dispose in the thread could be an issue. Try wrapping the SPSite call in a using statement to give .net back some control over the disposal. I have had multithreading in SP2010 working but it was a pig and had a lot of "unplanned features".

I did have a support call with Microsoft open at the time and their answer was that it should be possible but wasn't supported.